# Is there any KV data structure in Java which accepts key in primitive type?

Tags: java

I need to store information in Key Value manner. But the built-in Map interface cannot fit for my requirement. Java Map requires both Key and Values to be reference, while I need to use primitive value as key.

Is there any data structure something like Map ? Thanks for your help!

**Requirement Details:**

My server written in Java runs as a daemon listening a tcp port. When a user first connect in, details about the user need to be stored in KV manner, and the second time the user connect in, his details should be able to read from the KV data structure.

I cannot use the user object as key, for it will be destructed when disconnect, and reconstructed in the second connection. The two objects are not the same reference. Integer key doesn't fit for my requirement either for the same reason.

In other words, I need to use value as key, not reference.

Keys could be considered are: UUID(long), id(int) and so on. They are all primitive type.

Comment: Have you tried to google for "java map"?

Comment: Thank you @ChristianKuetbach, I have searched Google for a long time, and didn't find anything I need.

Comment: Quoi's answer to use wrappers is correct. Unlike C++, Java templates only work on classes, not primitives, so a wrapper is required.

Comment: Well after reading the question again, I remarked, that you have another question, "What is a Map in Java?" But why can't you use Integer as key? I can't imagine the problem...

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach, I thought when I use statement "new Integer(5)" to put and get, the keys are create twice, and they are not the same reference.

Comment: Sure new Integer is evil. Integer.valueOf(8) is even better. Comparison between two Integers are made with "Integer.valueOf(5).equals(Integer.valueOf(5))" (Maps uses the equals() of an object), So is is safe to use in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see why you can't simply wrap your primitive type in it's corresponding non-primitive class and use that as your key in a regular java map.

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
Integer key = Integer.valueOf(5);
Object test = new Object();
map.put(key, test);
Object test2 = map.get(Integer.valueOf(5));

test.equals(test2); // will be true
```

Comment: You don't have to create new Integers, autoboxing is ment for this.

Comment: Maybe it is what I was seeking. Thank you @pap

Answer (score 2):

Still you can go with java Map  as wrapper classes are available for all primitive type and java supports auto boxing, So you can use `java.util.Map`. ex -

```
Map<Long,Integer> map = new HashMap<Long,Integer>();
long uuid=10; int i= 10;
map.put(uuid,i);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, collections don't suport primitive types, so you have to use a wrapper classes for primitive types or array.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a Hashmap.

```
Hashmap<Long, Integer> dict=new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
dict.put(24,10);
dict.put(13,63);
dict.get(13); // Equals 63
```

Essentially, a HashMap will take the first argument as a key, and the second as the value, exactly as you requested. You can assign any type, including a Long for larger integers than normal, although you can't pass primitives. Still, this hasn't ever been an issue for me.

Comment: Sorry for my previous title, which may not express me clearly. Classes inherit from Map cannot fit for my requirement.

Comment: This is wrong `dict.get(13)` will return null. To get 63 you need to run `dict.get(Long.valueOf(13))`

Answer (score 0):

The `HashMap` class is fine for using key-value pairs, but there is no such thing which accepts primitive types.

We'll still try to use a primitive type in the context of a Map.

```
HashMap<Integer, V> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(12, someV);
```

As we write `map.put(12, someV)`, in fact, one cannot use a primitive type as the first argument of the method 'put' of class `java.util.Map`. But in Java, the integer '12' will automatically be *'converted'* (*auto-boxed*) into the correspondenting wrapper class, in this case `Integer`.

So that means that there is actually an **object** of type `Integer` in the `HashMap`, but it is **reflected** as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

various implementations exist elsewhere, but not in the standard java library. See for example [LongHashMap](https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev/blob/master/net/minecraft/server/LongHashMap.java).